# Asp.Net Web Application, Single Source, Multiple instances - one per Company

Tags: asp.net

I was just wondering if anyone could help with the following?

I have an asp.net application; vs2010 .net framework 4 with sql 2008 backend using forms authentication and published via iis 7 currently serving one company.  I will need to roll this out to multiple companies but wish to have one instance of the asp source code and separate sql instances.  The idea being each company can only access their respected data - which must be separated but all share the 'out of the box' application.

My head is currently hurting from the options! I have referenced the current connection string throughout the application and am wondering whether to either:

A) Host multiple copies of the application with separate web configs with the same connection string name, not ideal

B) Add multiple connection strings to the existing web config and somehow select which one to use - maybe via a dedicated login page for example

C) Some sort of multi tenant architecture?

Any advice would be great!

Many thanks

Comment: First thing I'd recommend is reconsidering having multiple databases. If you keep your companyID or whatever on all of your tables and queries, then having one database will make life a lot easier, especially as you get more and more companies added.

Comment: But if you stick with multiple databases, I'd probably have one "master" database with just all of your customers, and either connection strings for each of them, or some kind of identifier that can turn into a connection string. Then your web.config would have a single connection string, and you can add more companies without disrupting your app or config.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your reply! Thats great advice thank you, il go with the single instance with multiple databases.  Could you possibly recommend how would i amend the connection string to include this db value?

Comment: If possible, you should re-architect the solution itself to support multi-tenancy from one database. That will ensure a single codebase . What you might face (and I've been there) is different companies asking for different new features or modifications to existing features - that becomes very tricky in a single-instance architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sh1rts! you make a very good point, perhaps a solution would be from both suggestions and hold multiple databases within an instance, seperate virtual directories that could point to a seperate source for each with their own config.  When i update the code i could update the replicas by replacing the other companies aspx files etc, this would allow for customisations per company if required?

Comment: @Cuppachee Regarding your connection string question - your web.config would just have one connection string, for your "Clients" database. That database could have a table with two columns: ClientID and ConnectionString (the entire thing). Your app would just need to pass in the ClientID to this database, and retrieve its ConnectionString, then use that connection string to query the real database for that client. Ideally you'd cache these in memory for awhile to avoid having to query your Clients database over and over.

Comment: @Cuppachee About each company getting their own features - even if you find a good way to set it up, you're just giving yourself a hard time in the future. Suddenly you can't just develop, test, and release a new feature once - if you have 10 clients with 10 slightly different codebases, you now have to develop, test, and release the change 10 times. Unless you have a very good reason (a lot more money would however be a good reason), I'd avoid customizing per client.